# TTS with a websocket:Creating a WAV from binary data fails

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I try to create a WAV from binary data using the websocket connection on a node.js server. I use the BluemixTTS to create the speech. Here is my current code:

```
'use strict';
const WebSocket = require('ws');
var express = require('express');
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var vcapServices = require('vcap_services');
var extend = (extend = require('util')._extend);
var fs = require('fs');


var ttsConfig = extend(
    {
        version: 'v1',
        url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api',
        username: 'myusernamehere',
        password: "mypasswordhere"
    },
    vcapServices.getCredentials('text_to_speech')
);

var ttsAuthService = watson.authorization(ttsConfig);


var  websocket;
ttsAuthService.getToken({ url: ttsConfig.url }, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error retrieving token: ', err);

        return;
    }

    var voice = 'en-US_AllisonVoice';
    var wsURI = 'wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=' +
        voice + '&watson-token=' + token;


    websocket = new WebSocket(wsURI);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };

});

function onOpen(evt) {

    var message = {
        text: 'Hello world',
        accept: 'audio/wav',
        timings: ['words']
    };
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}
var messages;
var audioStream = null;

function onMessage(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.data === 'string') {
        messages += evt.data;
    } else {

        if(audioStream == null){
            audioStream = evt.data;
        }else{
            audioStream += evt.data;
        }
    }

}

function onClose(evt) {

    console.log(messages);
    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('test.wav');
    wstream.write((audioStream));
    wstream.end();

}

function  onError(evt) {

}
```

I get the token, trigger the TTS specifying audio/wav, build my buffer in the onMessage method and then write it into a .wav file. Everything seems fine.

However the file is somehow broken, and cannot be opened with any music-player. Do I miss some special encoding ?

Any help is appreciated
Regards,
Rambazamba

Answer (score 0):

As the data contains a buffer one has to write the buffer in the file directly each time you get a message and then close the file stream in the onClose event. Like this:

```
var messages;
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('test.wav');
function onMessage(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.data === 'string') {
        messages += evt.data;
    } else {
        wstream.write(evt.data)
    }

}

function onClose(evt) {
    console.log(messages);
    wstream.end();
}

function  onError(evt) {

}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, i never received close event back even after waiting for couple of mins